# Bitmap problems when making a background class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, text

So I'm updating my text adventure engine by making the document class smaller by shoving all the functions that could be put in a separate class into a separate class to save on space since the main class was having an excess of 1000 lines. (mostly from the array that held the story and such)

Currently, I'm in the process of moving the background changing function into it's own class and have run into some problems.

```
public class Background extends Bitmap
{

    public function Background(part:Object,width:Number,height:Number)
    {

        // add new background
        this.height = width
        this.width = height

    }

}
```

I have no idea how to set an image to this. part is part of an object array that kind of looks like this

```
        "PartName":
            {
                "text":""
                "choices":
                    {
                        "response1":
                            {
                                "text":"",
                                "nextPart":""
                            }
                    },
                            "background":Assets.dumpster
            },
```

Assets is just a class that holds all the embeds for the backgrounds.

Does anyone know how I can set the image of the part to the background class? Should I even be extending Bitmap?

Comment: What do you mean by "*object array*"? Is this a JSON string that you are trying to deserailize into an object?

Answer (score 1):

So if Assets.dumpster is the direct reference to the embedded image, you can

```
var Asset = part.background;
var bmp = new Asset() as Bitmap;
```

to get a bitmap, which makes it pointless for your background class to be extending Bitmap. You could make it a Sprite or even keep it "pure" and use it just as a creation/management point